# iphone Parse multiple Xml file

Tags: xml

I need to parse xml files stored in document directory.
I am parsing using XmlParser.

I was looping it in for loop

```
for (NSString *s in fileList){

    NSString *xmlPath1 =[xmlPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@",s];

    xmlParser = [[XMLParser alloc] loadXMLByURL:xmlPath1];

}
```

Comment: So ? What is your problem. What do you really want to know ?

Comment: XMLParser is parser class i am using,I am getting value of 'title tag of first xml file to all consecutive files